# How can I include a subset of a .cpp file in a Doxygen comment?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm trying to write some Doxygen comment blocks, and I'd like to include example snippets of code.  Of course, I'd like the examples to actually compile so they don't get stale.

My example.cpp (that I \include in the .h file) looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "../types_lib/Time_Limiter.h"
#include <vector>

void tl_demo () {
    // scarce will be a gate to control some resource that shouldn't get called
    // more than 10 times a second
    Time_Limiter scarce (10);

    // here's a bunch of requests
    std::vector<int> req (500);

    for (size_t i=0;i<req.size ();i++) {
        scarce.tick ();
        // once we get here, we know that we haven't ticked
        // more than 10 times in the last second.

        // do something interesting with req[i]
    }
}

// endcode
```

and my header file (that I'm running Doxygen) looks like this:

```
/**
 * \ingroup types_lib
 *
 * \class   Time_Limiter
 *
 * \brief   Thread safe gate used to control a resource (such as an internet quote service) that has a limit on how often you can call it.
 *
 * \dontinclude Time_Limiter_example.cpp
 * \skipline void
 * \until endcode
 * 
**/
```

And I'd like to get doxygen to just include stuff starting at "void demo" to the end of the file (but without the // endcode).

I've tried experimenting with \dontinclude and \skip, \skipline, and \until, and I can't quite figure out the right incantations.

EDIT:  included my .h file, and now I've almost got the right incantation.  This does *almost* exactly what I want, is there some way to use \until without a tag, and get rid of that last // endcode line from example.cpp?

Comment: Did you properly set the EXAMPLE_PATH in the doxyfile?

Comment: Yes.   the text is included, I'm just trying to figure out some incantation so that I don't have to see the three #includes at the beginning.

Comment: And you saw the example at http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html#cmddontinclude ?

Comment: It may be easier if you posted what you tried

Comment: For your question about the "endcode" comment: I *think* that \until with an "impossible" pattern will go until the end of the file.

Comment: Yeah, I tried \until xyzzy, and that doesn't work.   For now I'll just move the // endcode up onto the same line as the final closing brace.  Another thing I've gotten to work is to split the code for the function off into a file all its own, and just include that.  Then the project I have to build examples has some weirdness.  Oh well, I guess trying to get 100% isn't feasible.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED to add 2nd arg to clip macro.

Here's what I've done, which seems to work for me.  Mostly taken from hint from EricM....

my source file Time_Limiter_example.cpp is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "../types_lib/Time_Limiter.h"
#include <vector>

void tl_demo () {
    // scarce will be a gate to control some resource that shouldn't get called
    // more than 10 times a second
    Time_Limiter scarce (10);

    // here's a bunch of requests
    std::vector<int> req (500);

    for (size_t i=0;i<req.size ();i++) {
        scarce.tick ();
        // once we get here, we know that we haven't ticked
        // more than 10 times in the last second.

        // do something interesting with req[i]
    }
} // endcode

void tl_demo_short () 
{
} //endcode
```

And I want to include it, but not have the #includes at the top.

I defined an ALIAS in my Doxyfile as:

```
ALIASES += clip{2}="\dontinclude \1 \n \skipline \2 \n \until endcode"
```

And in my header, my comment looks like this:

```
/**
 * \ingroup types_lib
 *
 * \class   Time_Limiter
 *
 * \brief   Thread safe gate used to control a resource (such as an internet quote service) that has a limit on how often you can call it.
 *
 * \clip{Time_Limiter_example.cpp,tl_demo}
**/
```

And that does exactly what I want, including just the funciton tl_demo () from the .cpp file.

Comment: **This works only if we add "endcode" comment manually**, hence `@snippet` should be used instead (see the other answer, which needs two comments to mark, but is less confusing, and you can change function-name without worry).

Answer (score 3):

Something rather powerful is the `snippet` command. Say you have a function like this:

```
/*!@brief Factory
 *
 * Creates sthg
 */
sthg* Create();
```

And you would like to add a part of the file `sthgTests/sthg_factory.cpp`:

- Edit `sthgTests/sthg_factory.cpp` and add a tag around the part of the code you would like to appear in the documentation (say using a tag named `test_factory`) like this:

  ```
  //! [test_factory]
  void test_factory()
  {
    // code here
  }
  //! [test_factory]
  ```
- Then use the snippet command like this:

  ```
  /*!@brief Factory
   *
   * Creates sthg
   * @snippet sthgTests/sthg_factory.cpp test_factory
   */
  sthg* Create();
  ```

This approach is easy to setup and rather cheap to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I think [\verbinclude](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdverbinclude) should allow you to include a file as code and not have to put `// \endcode` at the last line.

EDIT: To clarify, I am suggesting that you put the code you want to include in its own include file, and use `#include` in the CPP file, and then use `\verbinclude` in the doxygen header file.

You source file would look like:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "../types_lib/Time_Limiter.h"
#include <vector>    
#include "Time_Limiter_example.inc"
```

The file "Time_Limiter_example.inc" can then contain just the code example:

```
void tl_demo () {
    // scarce will be a gate to control some resource that shouldn't get called
    // more than 10 times a second
    Time_Limiter scarce (10);

    // here's a bunch of requests
    std::vector<int> req (500);

    for (size_t i=0;i<req.size ();i++) {
        scarce.tick ();
        // once we get here, we know that we haven't ticked
        // more than 10 times in the last second.

        // do something interesting with req[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, but that doesn't do what I want, which is to include only a subset of the file.